# Accessing dynamic collection in mongodb through mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been trying to access a collection that was dynamically created in the database through {$out: "Accepted"} in nodejs using mongoose. the collection was successfully created.

from the controller:

```
exports.accepted = async (req, res, next)=>{
     await Pupil.aggregate([{$match: {status: "Accepted"}}, {$out: "Accepted" }])
     **Accepted.find({}).then(result=>{
        res.render('home/accepted', {results: result, pageTitle: 'accepted page'})
 }).catch(error=>{
     console.log(error)*emphasized text*
 });**
}
```

I want to retrieve the documents in that 'Accepted' collection and render them to the ejs file.

the error message is:

```
    Accepted.find({}).then(result=>{
         ^
    
ReferenceError: Accepted is not defined at exports.accepted...
```

can someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow @Jerevick

There are two possible cases here:

#### Case 1 - You don't need to write to a new collection

You just want to find documents of accepted pupils and render them in the EJS template, in which case:

**A)** You don't need to write your documents into a new collection, you can just get them from the result and pass them to your template.

```js
exports.accepted = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const result = await Pupil.aggregate([{ $match: { status: 'Accepted' } }]);
    res.render('home/accepted', { results: result, pageTitle: 'accepted page' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

**B)** You don't even need the aggregation framework, you can just do a simple find:

```js
exports.accepted = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const result = await Pupil.find({ status: 'Accepted' });
    res.render('home/accepted', { results: result, pageTitle: 'accepted page' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

#### Case 2 - you need to write to a new collection, and your example was just to simplify

If that's the case, it's important to emphasize the difference between mongoose and MongoDB. Mongoose is a wrapper around the native MongoDB driver to help with casting, and provide a nicer API.

When you add a new collection to the database using the [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) stage, the mongoose isn't aware of it and it doesn't assign a model for it and has no idea what kind of data live there, in which case you would need to bypass mongoose and use the native MongoDB driver directly.

I highly advise against this approach, since you'd be giving up all the convenience mongoose provides, don't take this approach unless you really know what you're doing, there's probably a better solution than using the native driver directly.

```js
exports.accepted = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    await Pupil.aggregate([{ $match: { status: 'Accepted' } }, { $out: 'Accepted' }]);
    const acceptedCollection = mongoose.connection.collection('Accepted');

    const result = await acceptedCollection.find({}).toArray();
    res.render('home/accepted', { results: result, pageTitle: 'accepted page' });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Here's a full reproduction script you can play with:

#### 65209755.js

```js
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const assert = require('assert');


run().catch(console.error);

async function run () {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  });

  await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();

  const studentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    status: String
  });

  const User = mongoose.model('User', studentSchema);


  await User.insertMany([
    { name: 'Hafez1', status: 'Accepted' },
    { name: 'Hafez2', status: 'Accepted' },
    { name: 'Hafez3', status: 'Accepted' },
    { name: 'Hafez4', status: 'Rejected' },
    { name: 'Hafez5', status: 'Rejected' }
  ]);


  await User.aggregate([
    { $match: { status: 'Accepted' } },
    { $out: 'acceptedstudents' }
  ]);

  const db = mongoose.connection;
  const acceptedStudents = await db.collection('acceptedstudents').find({}).toArray();
  assert.deepStrictEqual(
    acceptedStudents.map(student => student.name),
    ['Hafez1', 'Hafez2', 'Hafez3']
  );

  console.log('All assertions passed.');
}
```

#### Output

```
$ node 65209755.js
All assertions passed.
```

Comment: this works well. thanks! my idea is to be able to remove the document whose status is 'Accepted' from the Pupil collection and store it in a separate collection for future use whilst keeping the Pupil collection clean

Comment: I can't think of any benefits of separating accepted pupils in a different collection, there isn't any performance of separating documents in different collections over a simple index on the `status` field. It's much more trouble with no real benefit.